# Java Swing: Full Screen mode not working

Tags: java, swing, awt, fullscreen, key-bindings

I am trying to achieve FULL SCREEN mode in my Java APP which is based on [this code](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/fullscreen/exclusivemode.html)

```
private static void createAndShowGUI()
{
    //Create and set up the window.
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Mouse Click Demo");
    //Make it non-Resizable
    frame.setResizable(false);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    //Create and set up the content pane.
    JComponent newContentPane = new MouseEventDemo();
    newContentPane.setOpaque(true); //content panes must be opaque
    frame.setContentPane(newContentPane);

    //Display the window.
    frame.pack();
    //frame.setVisible(true);
    if (!frame.isDisplayable())
    {
        // Can only do this when the frame is not visible
        frame.setUndecorated(true);
    }
    GraphicsDevice gd = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getDefaultScreenDevice();
    try
    {
      if(gd.isFullScreenSupported())
      {
         gd.setFullScreenWindow(frame);
         System.out.print("DOES SUPPORT");
      }
      else
      {
          //Can't run in full screen mode
          System.out.print("DOES NOT SUPPORT");
      }
      frame.setVisible(true);
    }
    finally
    {
     gd.setFullScreenWindow(null);
    }

}
```

Thing is that when I run on Macbook it still shows top Mac bar and bottom Deck, The console does enter in condition and print **DOES SUPPORT** but still does not show in Full Screen mode.

What's wrong am I doing?

Edit: [This is my Screen Shot](http://oi48.tinypic.com/17u9ur.jpg)

Comment: I probably wouldn't call `frame.setResizable(false);`, it can do some weird and whacky things if not called in the correct order.  This probably no point in call `frame.pack();` either, unless full screen support is not available, but call it then, not before

Comment: calling frame.pack later is not showing screen at all. I did try that. In main post I also have added Screen shot of my screen.

Comment: Ok found the culprit, example was calling *finally* which was making it into normal window again. I had to restart my machine since ESC was not working either to exit Full Screen mode

Comment: @MadProgrammer After entering in full screen mode how do I bin ESC key of Macbook to exit full screen?

Comment: Take a look at [Key Bindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) (hope you don't mind but I had a little giggle over problem - but I feel your pain as I'm pretty sure I've fallen into that trap to ;))

Comment: this si what I am doing and checking some of your other posts here :)

Answer (score 3):

In response to your <kbd>Escape</kbd> comment...

You best choice is to use [Key Bindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html)

Lots of reasons, but the main one is that it doesn't suffer from the exclusive focus issues that `KeyListener` does

```
public class TickleMe {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TickleMe();
    }

    public TickleMe() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                }

                final JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setUndecorated(true);

                JPanel content = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
                content.add(new JLabel("Tickle Me"));
                InputMap im = content.getInputMap(JPanel.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW);
                ActionMap am = content.getActionMap();
                im.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_ESCAPE, 0), "getMeOutOfHere");
                am.put("getMeOutOfHere", new AbstractAction() {
                    @Override
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                        try {
                            GraphicsDevice gd = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getDefaultScreenDevice();
                            gd.setFullScreenWindow(null);
                        } finally {
                            frame.dispose();
                        }
                    }
                });

                frame.setContentPane(content);

                GraphicsDevice gd = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getDefaultScreenDevice();
                if (gd.isFullScreenSupported()) {
                    gd.setFullScreenWindow(frame);
                    frame.requestFocusInWindow();
                }

            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok found the culprit, example was calling *finally* which was making it into normal window again. I had to restart my machine since ESC was not working either to exit Full Screen mode.